# issues using htmlspecialchars on value before submitting page

Tags: php

How clean all the values on my form before submit using htmlspecialchars().

Part of my code is the following;

```
<form method = "post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<div>UserName</div>
<input type="text" name="user_username" size="20" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_username']);?>">
```

I am using vaule=htmlspecialchars because I want to return with error to the same page and keep the same info entered, but I found that I am having data inside before submit. how can I fix that

I

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez That is not the issue here. Read the question again ;-)

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "but I found that I am having data inside before submit" ?

Comment: show the generated html, because what you have above cannot "leak" data...

Comment: In the file, where your form placed, php-code is not processed . Perhaps, it  has html extension

Comment: sorry, I'm realizing that the info that is showing in the input before submit the page is an error of the variable that is not defined at the beginning, how initialize the $_POST['user_username'] at the beginning?, I mean before submit the page.

Comment: if I delete the <?php echo "htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_username']);?>" on value, it will work fine

Comment: No problem I solved writting more code :-)  value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['user_username'])) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_username']);} else { echo "";}?>"